# How to stop 6-axis robot motion by trigger?

Tags: ros2, robotic-arm, movement, move-group-interface

I have my 6-axis robot.

*ros2 rolling
c++*

*moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface move_group_interface*

After planning the path I use **move_group_interface.execute(plan)** to move robot.

I'd like to break the motion and stop robot by trigger (for example trigger from external sensor). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any execute-cancel feature in the [moveit2 move_group API](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/main/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h). The standard `move_group.execute()` method passes your trajectory plan to a separate `FollowJointTrajectory` action server. You can do the same from your own code.

You can create an action client and use it rather than using the `move_group.execute()` method. That action client object has a cancel operation which should do what you want.

For reference, you can look at the `execute()` code in `move_group_interface.cpp` to see how they did it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it.